# Magento: Proper way to iterate over a Varien Object collection

Tags: magento, object, collections, magento-1.7

If I were to create a `collection` that would retrieve all `products` belonging to `category` with a given `ID`, as below:

```
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();  
    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
    $category   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(39);
    $catName    = $category->getName();

    $visibility = array(  
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,  
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG  
    );  

    $products = $product->setStoreId($storeId)  
        ->getCollection()  
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)  
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)  
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'), 'inner')
        ->setOrder('name', 'asc')
    ;  

    $collection = $products;
```

How would I then iterate over the collection and access each item's data, item being a product in this case.

I would have expected something like the below to give me each items available data but doesn't seem to work:

```
    foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($value->getData());
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're close. Try doing

```
foreach ($collection as $obj) {
        echo $obj->getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, turned out I hadn't re-indexed the category tables and my code above did work...